# Send email to multiple user along with active user in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code which is sending email to active user in Google sheet, but I want to send that email to more recipients.

I have prepared this which is sending email to active user, but need to have multiple users, maybe by giving their email ids in the code somehow?

```
MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Rollcoll Pending List", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
  }else{ Logger.log("Roll bCk Data is 0")}
}
```

It should send email to active user along with other email ids, which I want to have in this code with commas separated or something. The purpose is to send email to multiple users once this gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your multiple users in your contacts under a group name and retrieve them in an array using this function.  This function returns all of the emails separated by commas so that you can add them to the recipient;

```
function getGroupEmails(groupname) {
  var emailA=[];
  var grps=ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
  for(var i=0;i<grps.length;i++) {
    //Logger.log(grps[i].getName());
    if(grps[i].getName()==groupname) {
      var cA=grps[i].getContacts();
      for(var j=0;j<cA.length;j++) {
        var eA=cA[j].getEmails();
        for(var k=0;k<eA.length;k++) {
          emailA.push(eA[k].getAddress());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(emailA);
  return emailA.join(',');
}
```

returns an email string with all of the emails separated by commas.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(getGroupEmails(groupname),
                    "Rollcoll Pending List", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
```

Just create a new groups. Add your contacts.  And use that groupname in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add several emails in the recipient, like this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + "," + "email_1" + "," + "email_2"+"," + "email_3", "Rollcoll Pending List", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
```

You can also do it with an array of emails.